# Create a layout based in percentages

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do my first app.

I'm doing a layout that contains four rows. There will be a title in the first row (10% height), two images in the second (40% height), two images in the third (40% height) and a button in the fourth (10% height).

Right now, I'm using a linear layout with vertical orientation. Using weight sum and weight, I have the correct proportion on each row.

But, if I use in the second and the third rows linear layout weight, then I get a warning about nested weights and bad performance.  I understand the bad performance issue, but I don't know how to solve my problem without them.

I need each image be a 50% of its parent width.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: That is a quick mockup of what i'm trying to accomplish
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/252856/androidlayout.jpg

Comment: In my experience, I've always been worried about bad performance but never noticed it.  I've read into it in the past and it seems that this can be a problem especially if you doing this for a listview (where each row of a listview has nested weights) with say 1000 views in the list.  But with a static view, you probably don't have to worry

Comment: hi @jameo thanks for your reply. As i said, i'm learning android and i want to do that the right way since the begining. So, if google says it's the bad way, i would like to avoid it

Comment: Basically, you might be able to accomplish this a different way, but it will be overly complex and not work in all situations. Just because android is warning you doesn't mean its __wrong__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular situation you could make the two `ImageViews` occupy 50% of the parent's width without using weights with a block like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" 
     android:layout_weight="your_value">
     <View android:id="@+id/anchor" android:layout_width="0dp" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignRight="@id/anchor" /> 
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@id/anchor" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but i need the two images be 50% of the parent because the images are too big

Comment: @Chux Did you tried my code? The `RelativeLayout` group represents one 40% group in your layout's picture. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I know understand your solution, you only have to put an invisible view in the center because you want two colums, and align the edges of each image. But... what if i need 3 images per row?

Comment: @Chux If you want three columns(3 images horizontally) you're out of luck as you'll not be able to use my  `RelativeLayout`. You could always write a custom `ViewGroup` to divide its children in three columns pretty easy and without the need of weight.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look and consider whether you could make your layout work as a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). It's designed to handle situations where you want to arrange UI elements into a roughly grid-like pattern, while avoiding the performance issues that nested weights can cause. If your UI lends itself to this sort of layout, you can achieve both [simpler implementation and faster performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) by taking advantage of it.

GridLayout is supported as far back as API level 7, I believe, via the support library.